# Unable to connect to computer from outside LAN

Tags: networking, ip, netcat

I opened two terminal windows, and typed `nc -vv -lp 9999` in the first one and`nc -vv $(dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com) 9999` in the second. However, the two netcats didn't connect, and I got

```
Warning: forward host lookup failed for 11.22.333.44.in-addr.arpa [44.333.22.11] 9999 (?) : Connection timed out
```

, where instead of 44.333.22.11 was my real ip.
I turned off the INPUT block with iptables, turned off my router firewall, but nothing changed. However, when I try `nc -vv 127.0.0.1 9999`, or `nc -vv 192.168.1.4 9999` (my ip in LAN), it works just fine. What could go wrong?
UPD
I have just tested the possibility of connecting from another computer outside my network, but it failed too.

```
nc -vv my.i.p.address 9999
```

I used the same command with my public IP on another machine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com
```

is a way of finding out what your IP address is *on the internet* by using a third-party "resolver1.opendns.com" *outside your network*.

Since you're behind a NAT, your machine has no way of finding out how to route these packets to you.

So long as your router supports "loopback addressing" (routing internal packets destined for your public IP back to you) your router would still need to know that those packets are destined for your *internal* IP address on that port. This is known as **Port Forwarding**.

If you add a port forward to your router for port 9999 to your internal IP address  192.168.1.4 then it *might* work but most SOHO modem/routers don't support this kind of behaviour since it's exceptionally unusual in normal operations.  The use case being that if you are inside the LAN, why would you not communicate via the LAN IP?

The only situation I've seen this kind of usage has been in a poorly-configured DNS resolver.  If you have a local DNS server, then it should be replying with the internal IP for local services, not sending all traffic via the internet.

Comment: That didn't actually solve my problem, as I wanted to connect from another computer, but when it failed, I began to experiment with connecting to myself

Comment: From another computer inside or outside your network?

Comment: outside........

Comment: Ah missed that.  Comment deleted.

Comment: @MintLover It will still fail for the same reason - You need to forward the port on your NAT, publicIP:9999 -> privateIP:9999